# What name is given to tests that determine if a system will run an application?

Tags: testing, requirements

I want to essentially check the environment and see if the necessary conditions for my application are in place.  That is not unit testing, what is the name for that?

EDIT:  I found an example whilst doing something else: [otrs.checkModules](http://doc.otrs.org/2.4/en/html/x531.html#installation-of-perl-modules), from the much-since-last-time-I-looked OTRS ticketing system.  That is what I am talking about. Hopefully that clarifies the question somewhat?

Comment: If it's not unit testing, why did you tag it as that?

Comment: @peachykeen  Fair enough. Testing seemed too vague, and the answer to my question would be what I will use in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might call it precondition testing, but I don't think that's an official term.  But you are essentially trying to assert the preconditions in order to execute your app.

Comment: Sure. Or environmental testing.  It's killing me, there must be a name  for this, right?